# Make Box<Self> function parameter mutable

Tags: rust

I've got this code snippet ([playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d1cc542f3a2b331f6d6d03ccbb94d779)) where I'm basically trying to change a *trait* implementation to allow a state change for the *struct* it's applied to.

The current method signature is:

```rust
fn approve(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn State>
```

, but I need to make it into something like

```rust
fn approve(&mut self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn State>
```

This doesn't compile. I've yet to see a Rust `&mut self` parameter definition along with a type, though I'm not sure why that would be an issue.

If I try:

```rust
fn approve(&mut self) -> Box<dyn State>
```

I get other compile-time errors when I try to return an unmodified `self` from the method.

---

For a little bit more context (before checking the playground), here are some relevant code bits:

```rust
trait State {
    fn approve(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn State>;
}

struct Draft {
    approve_count: u8,
}

impl State for Draft {
    fn approve(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn State> {
        // self.approve_count += 1;
        if self.approve_count == 2 {
            Box::new(Approved {})
        } else {
            self
        }
    }
}

struct Approved {}

impl State for Approved { ... }
```

What I would like to do is be able to uncomment the `self.approve_count += 1;` line and have it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax for a mutable reference is:

```
fn approve(self: &mut Box<Self>)
```

...but then you won't be able to return `self` as `Box<dyn State>` because you're only holding a *reference* to self.

If all you need is for `self.approve_count += 1` to work, you don't need to switch to `&mut self`, you can simply declare `mut self: Box<Self>`:

```
impl State for Draft {
    fn approve(mut self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn State> {
        self.approve_count += 1;
        if self.approve_count == 2 {
            Box::new(Approved {})
        } else {
            self
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6f9b405e144ebe1231bd53570caeff50)

That code is a bit suspect in that it modifies `self.approved_count` even in the case where the function returns a completely new `Approved` instance (and discards the just incremented value), but that may be fixed by moving the increment into the `else` clause and adjusting the test as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks! I was surprised to see that I can add the `mut` keyword to one implementation, but I don't need to put it in the trait's function definition. I thought it's part of the method signature, but I guess that's not the case. In fact, when I change the trait definition to `fn approve(mut self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn State>;` I get a compile time error: `error: patterns aren't allowed in functions without bodies`.

Comment: @carpdan Yes, it doesn't matter whether an owned variable is mut or not because you can always use `let mut x = x` to _make_ it mutable (or `let x = x` to make it immutable). In Rust the owner has the final say regarding mutability of data.